# TypeScript declaration merging - changing a property type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Is it possible to change the type of a property that is declared in an interface? I don't know how to explain this in words, so here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do that doesn't work:

Assume that the `Movie` namespace is defined in a 3rd-party library that I don't control:

```
declare namespace Movie {
  interface Character {
    doSomething(): Promise<void>;
    friend: Character;
  }
}
```

Now in my application, I want my character to be Super, with Super friends. So I tried to do this in my own typings:

```
declare namespace Movie {
  interface Character {
    doAnExtraThing(): Promise<void>; // OK to add a new method
    nickname: string;                // OK to add a new property
    friend: SuperCharacter;          // NOT OK to override type with a subtype
  }

  interface SuperCharacter extends Character {
    doSomethingSuper(): Promise<void>;
  }
}
```

That doesn't work though, because TypeScript won't allow me to override the `friend` property type with `SuperCharacter`, even though by definition a `SuperCharacter` ***is*** a `Character`. TypeScript complains with this error:

```
[ts] Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
'friend' must be of type 'Character', but here has type 'SuperCharacter'.
```

I was hoping that by having `SuperCharacter` extend the original `Character` interface I wouldn't have this problem, but I do.

Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to specify explicitly that `friend` can be a `SuperCharacter` since `SuperCharacter` is already a `Character`.

So you can remove this block entirely:

interface Character {
    friend: SuperCharacter;
  }

As proof, we can step away from interfaces and look at an implementation with classes that will compile properly:

```
class Character {
  friend?: Character

  constructor(friend?: Character) {
    this.friend = friend
  }

  doSomething() {}
}

class SuperCharacter extends Character {
  doSomethingSuper() {}
}


new Character(new Character())
new Character(new SuperCharacter())
new SuperCharacter(new Character())
new SuperCharacter(new SuperCharacter())
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my use case. Like I said in the original post, _I want my character to be Super, with Super friends_, meaning that I should be able to do `const character = new Character()`, then `character.doSomethingSuper()` or `character.friend.doSomethingSuper()`.

Comment: In that situation, you'd need to instantiate a SuperCharacter to begin with: `const character = new SuperCharacter()`.  A method from a child class such as `doSomethingSuper()` will never appear on a parent!

Comment: I have no control over how the instance is created. My question is specifically about how to change the type of a property on an existing interface to a new ***compatible*** type (as is the case with subtypes) via declaration merging. It's possible to add new properties to an interface, but it seems like it's not possible to change the type of a property, even if the new type is compatible with the original one.

Comment: In your example, though, you're not adding new properties to an existing interface, you're creating a brand new interface that extends an existing one. It's also important to note the two types are not truly compatible. A SuperCharacter is a type of Character, but a Character is not a SuperCharacter. The only way you could make these two types match is if you extended the Character directly to include a `doSomethingSuper()` method.

Comment: My point was that it is *possible* to introduce entirely new properties to an existing interface, not that I needed to. I've updated the example to show how that's possible though. However, what I need is to override a property type. Like you said, a `SuperCharacter` still *is* a `Character`, so one should be able to provide a `SuperCharacter` wherever a `Character` is required (not the other way around). So far, it just seems like a limitation of the TypeScript compiler, and that what I'm trying to do simply isn't possible.

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Merott no, you can't make an existing interface type more restrictive. It already accepts a Character, and you can't force that Character to be a SuperCharacter on the existing interface type. And honestly that is a concept I don't know a single language that would allow it.

Comment: @Merott you can add a superFriend property that is of type super though.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two solutions:

## Solution 1

You can also accomplish the same result a pirix-gh's answer with a union type and a conditional type.

First we merge 2 types together with:

`type Merge<T, U> = T & U`

Then we can use a conditional type to change the field friend:

```
type ChangeProperty<T, K extends keyof T, U> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: Prop extends K ? U : T[Prop]
}
```

To produce the needed type use it like this:

```
// From the namespace
interface Character {
    doSomething(): Promise<void>;
    friend: Character;
}

interface SuperCharacter extends Character {
    doSomethingSuper(): Promise<void>;
}

type MyCharacter =  ChangeProperty<Merge<SuperCharacter, SuperCharacter>, "friend", SuperCharacter>
```

With this approach you don't have to add a field to SuperCharacter, you reuse the `friend` field and change its type to `SuperCharacter`.

## Solution 2

This one is based on pirix-gh's answer, but without the library. Also using a union and a conditional type.

```
type SuperMerge<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof (T & U)]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never
}
```

The type `SuperMerge` combines T and U and then iterates over it props then when the property is in T it uses the type in T else it will use the type in U. The never part will never happen.

You can use it like this:

```
interface SuperCharacter extends Character {
    doSomethingSuper(): Promise<void>;
    friend: SuperCharacter // You need to this line in order to overwrite the default
}
```

With this solution you need to add the field friend with its new type to the interface in order to overwrite the default. The first type is containing all leading properties and will be kept, so if there are any dupliciates in the second type the information will be overwritten by the first. The second types only function is to extend the first type with extra properties.

`type MyCharacter = SuperMerge<SuperCharacter, Character>`

## Conclusion

Both solutions output the same result:

```
type MyCharacter = {
    doSomethingSuper: () => Promise<void>;
    doSomething: () => Promise<void>;
    friend: SuperCharacter;
}
```

In order to chose one I think both have there pros and cons. The first solution is usefull when you want to merge 2 types you don't have controll over, however you can change only 1 type at the time. You can call use `ChangeType` recursively to change more properties.

With solution 2 you can just at new properties to a new type and all the properties with the same name will be overwitten by the first type.

With both solutions you can merge with your own types.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this with the [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/pirix-gh/ts-toolbelt). But instead of having an interface you will have a `type`:

```
import {O} from 'ts-toolbelt'

interface Character {
    doSomething(): Promise<void>
    friend: Character
  }

interface SuperCharacter {
    doSomethingSuper(): Promise<void>;
    friend: SuperCharacter;
}

// SuperCharacter will override Character  
type SuperMerge = O.Merge<SuperCharacter, Character>

// type SuperMerge = {
//     doSomethingSuper: () => Promise<void>;
//     friend: SuperCharacter;
//     doSomething: () => Promise<void>;
// }
```

then do

```
interface SuperMergedCharacter extends SuperMerge {
 ...
}
```